# Timer not initialized after form loaded and shown

Tags: vb.net, timer, nullreferenceexception

My application worked until today several months. It is started many times a day, used by several different people and computers - and all these without any problems. Today I received log with simple exception connected to not initialized timer.

## Exception

```
Type = System.NullReferenceException
Message = Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
TargetSite = Void StartTimer()
StackTrace = at QMS.frmStart_Main.StartTimer() in frmStart_Main.vb:line 64
at QMS.frmStart_Main.frmStart_Main_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e) in frmStart_Main.vb:line 124
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnShown(EventArgs e)
...
```

Please don't start typing answer yet... :)

## Code

Head of frmStart_Main class has some private variables including Timer initilization:

```
Public Class frmStart_Main
    Implements IMessageFilter

    Private WithEvents t As New Timer() With {.Interval = 1000}

    ' May be not relevant to my problem but I prefer to show that it exists here as they are part of one of the methods described later on...
    Private formIsClosing As Boolean = False
    Private _timeToAutoClose As Integer = 60
    Private _cycleStart As Integer = _timeToAutoClose
    Private _cycleCurrent As Integer = _cycleStart
```

My Prefilter Message method which can be related. I add MessageFilter to my form later just before timer start. No problem with timer inside this method though.

```
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
    If (m.Msg >= &H100 And m.Msg <= &H109) Or (m.Msg >= &H200 And m.Msg <= &H20E) Then
        t.Stop()
        t.Start()
        _cycleStart = _timeToAutoClose
        _cycleCurrent = _cycleStart
        timerTick(Nothing, Nothing)
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

When form is loaded I do nothing connected to timer

```
Private Sub frm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Unrelated stuff here, nothing connected to timer
End Sub
```

When form is shown, I block 'Close' button, start some long running task in the background and after finishing the task I call method that starts the timer.

```
Private Sub frm_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown

        cmdClose.Disable

        bgworker = New BackgroundWorker With {.WorkerReportsProgress = True, .WorkerSupportsCancellation = True}
        AddHandler bgworker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted
        AddHandler bgworker.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bgworker_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler bgworker.DoWork, AddressOf StartUpCheck
        bgworker.RunWorkerAsync()

        While bgworker.IsBusy
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While

        Call StartTimer() 

    End Sub
```

And finally code of StartTimer method where exception is raised:

```
Private Sub StartTimer()
    Application.AddMessageFilter(Me)
    t.Start() ' <===== here we have an exception! Line 64.
End Sub
```

I apologize in advance for too long and maybe not related parts of code.

## Question

So, could you explain me why thousands of times this application worked and today one time it raised exception here? And how to rewrite critical part of timer code to avoid it in future?

## Update 1

When the form is closing I setup the flag `formIsClosing`

```
Private Sub frm_Closing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    formIsClosing = True
    Call StopTimer()

End Sub
```

And `StopTimer` method is:

```
Public Sub StopTimer()
    Application.RemoveMessageFilter(Me)
    If t IsNot Nothing Then
        t.Dispose()
        t = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

## Update 2

I see that I need to post also my `t.tick` method to have the story complete.

```
Private Sub timerTick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles t.Tick
    If Not formIsClosing Then
        If _cycleCurrent > 0 Then
            Me.pbTimeToClose.Maximum = _cycleStart
            Me.pbTimeToClose.Value = _cycleCurrent
            _cycleCurrent -= 1

            ' Unrelated stuff here...

        Else

            Call My.Application.DisposeAllFormsExceptMe(Me)
            Me.Close()

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Where is the Timer `t` created? 2) If you put `StartTimer()` in `bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted` then you wouldn't need the `While` loop with its call to `Application.DoEvents()` - the latter *might* be breaking it and is possibly doing things that you don't want.

Comment: `t` is initialized at the top of form as a `Private WithEvents t As New Timer() `. Method `StartTimer` must be in `MyBase.Shown` because after `bgworker` completes its job I need to check if all went right. If yes I `StartTimer`, if not I stop and close the form with some message to user. Part of code `While bgworker.IsBusy : Application.DoEvents() : End While` is a common way to wait for `bgworker` to finish its task without stoping UI responding. So the code that I presented is the minimum to understand that normally `t` is always initialized and should never raise exception.

Comment: It may be a common way, but that does not make it right. You want to start the timer when the bgworker has finished: the RunWorkerCompleted event is made for that. I suspect that it will be difficult to track down the root cause of the error - does the backgroundworker take a very long time to run?

Comment: No, depends of network, from 2 to 4 seconds. I'm confused... Everybody here says: 'don't use `Application.DoEvents()`, it's evil. OK. but almost everybody here also says: use `While: End While` to wait for task to finish.

Comment: If I do what you suggest, I also have to move `Application.AddMessageFilter(Me)` to `bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted` because as only user moves the mouse or type something `timer` will stop/start in `PreFilterMessage`.

Comment: 1) You don't need to wait for the task to finish because there is an event which is raised (i.e. RunWorkerCompleted). The `StartTimer()` method already has `Application.AddMessageFilter(Me)` - I don't see why you would need to add the latter in `bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted`. The program will not close itself just because the UI isn't doing anything. 2) Why does it matter if the user moves the mouse or types something: how does that affect what your program is doing?

Comment: Ad1) I get the point. I just move all my "post-task" checkings into `bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted` and inside this method I will call my method 'StartTimer' if all is ok or if it's not, I'll just close my app. Ad2) All this `PreFilterMessage` is my way to guarantee that application is actively used. If user moves the mouse or type something I restart timer in `PreFilterMessage` method. But after 60 seconds of inactivty I close the app (it's deleted this part of code above). `t.tick` method is used to update progress bar at the very bottom of the form to visualize time running out.

Comment: However I still don't understand why `t` is not initlized when form itself is initialized. Does it mean that other variables can also be uninitialized even when form is already shown. That's nonsense...

Comment: Aha! We may be on to something. In your app closing method, you should `RemoveHandler t.Tick, AddressOf <nameOfTheTickHandlerGoesHere>`. If the form was in the process of being torn down just at the wrong moment, it could have destroyed `t` but `StartTimer()` was called just afer that. **Or** you could could check for `If t IsNot Nothing Then ...` in the `StartTimer()` method to make sure it still exists.

Comment: Maybe we are closer but not fully :) Please see my Update 1 above. Is not enough to `RemoveMessageFilter` and dispose `t`?

Comment: In Update 2 above `t.tick` method where I check `formIsClosing` flag.

Comment: You need to remove the handler before disposing of `t`. However, it would be more robust to check for `If t IsNot Nothing Then ...` in the StartTimer() method. Also, do not use `t = Nothing` because it will interfere with the garbage collector.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Morton. I will implement all your suggestions.